# Error 1 Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers

Tags: vb.net

I have been getting this error in my Mysql connection. The code is for changing password. I have tried a lot but I have no way to resolve the error. Please, can anyone help.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Data

Public Class frmchpwd
    Dim myconnection As MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnProfileChangePwd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProfileChangePwd.Click
        Try
            Dim RowsAffected As Integer = 0
            If Len(Trim(OldPassword.Text)) = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter old password", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                OldPassword.Focus()
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If Len(Trim(NewPassword.Text)) = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter new password", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                NewPassword.Focus()
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If Len(Trim(ConfirmPassword.Text)) = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please confirm new password", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                ConfirmPassword.Focus()
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If NewPassword.TextLength < 5 Then
                MessageBox.Show("The New Password Should be of Atleast 5 Characters", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                NewPassword.Text = ""
                ConfirmPassword.Text = ""
                NewPassword.Focus()
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf NewPassword.Text <> ConfirmPassword.Text Then
                MessageBox.Show("Password do not match", "Input error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                NewPassword.Text = ""
                OldPassword.Text = ""
                ConfirmPassword.Text = ""
                OldPassword.Focus()
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf OldPassword.Text = NewPassword.Text Then
                MessageBox.Show("Password is same.. Re-enter new password", "Input error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                NewPassword.Text = ""
                ConfirmPassword.Text = ""
                NewPassword.Focus()
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If myconnection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                myconnection.Open()
            End If

            Dim hash, hashold As String
            Using md5Hash As MD5 = MD5.Create()
                hash = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, NewPassword.Text)
                hashold = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, OldPassword.Text)
            End Using

            Dim co As String = "UPDATE logininfo_tb SET password = '" & hash & "' WHERE user_id ='" & SqlSafe(curent_user_id) & "' and password = '" & hashold & "';"
            Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(co)
            cmd.Connection = myconnection
            RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If RowsAffected > 0 Then
                NewPassword.Text = ""
                OldPassword.Text = ""
                ConfirmPassword.Text = ""
                OldPassword.Focus()
                'tracksystemlogs("Changed Password")
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully changed", "Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                Me.Close()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("invalid email or password", "input error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                NewPassword.Text = ""
                OldPassword.Text = ""
                ConfirmPassword.Text = ""
                OldPassword.Focus()
            End If
            If myconnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                myconnection.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.Message.Contains("MySQL hosts") Then
                MessageBox.Show("Server not found", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

    Shared Function GetMd5Hash(ByVal md5Hash As MD5, ByVal input As String) As String
        ' Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash. 
        Dim data As Byte() = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input))

        ' Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes 
        ' and create a string. 
        Dim sBuilder As New StringBuilder()

        ' Loop through each byte of the hashed data  
        ' and format each one as a hexadecimal string. 
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To data.Length - 1
            sBuilder.Append(data(i).ToString("x2"))
        Next i

        ' Return the hexadecimal string. 
        Return sBuilder.ToString()
    End Function 'GetMd5Hash
End Class
```

Comment: Rather than posting that wall of code, how about posting just enough to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys i finally resolved it, in the MySqlConnection it was supposed to

Dim myconnection As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString). Hopes everyone will be blessed with this. Thanks.